# Replace a string using regular expression having two variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace two strings using regular expression value replacement so the resulting string is `$?tlang=es&text=Hello world`, so I didn't know to use here [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
const value = "Hello world"
const queryString = "?tlang=es&text=$1"
```

In this scenary, `value` and `queryString` are hard-coded, but in "real life" it should be the result of a regular expression group capturing like `line.match(/msgid \"(.*)\"/)` where `line` is an iterated text line and `queryString` is what the user submitted.

I thought I just could do this, but maybe it's too much effort where there is a better solution (that I couldn't find):

```
const line = "Full name: John Doe" // text input
const sourcePattern = /Full name: (.*) (.*)/ // user input
let queryString = 'name=$1&lname=$2' // user input
const matches = line.match(sourcePattern)
matches.splice(0, 1)

for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    queryString = queryString.replace(`\$${i+1}`, matches[i])
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are fine to extract the values from the first string. But for working with query strings there's a [built in class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) that helps:

```
const entries = [...new URLSearchParams(queryString).entries()]

if (matches.length !== entries.length) {
  // handle error
}

const replaced = entries.reduce((params, [key], index) => {
  params.append(key, matches[index]);
  return params;
}, new URLSearchParams());
```

You can call `toString()` on it to get the modified query string. Generally speaking you want to avoid doing string processing any time there's a readily available richer data type.

Comment: well, learned something new today, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could compact the code a little as follows:

```js
const line = "Full name: John Doe" // text input
const sourcePattern = /Full name: (.*) (.*)/ // user input
let queryString = 'name=$1&lname=$2' // user input
const [_, ...matches] = line.match(sourcePattern)

console.log(queryString.split(/\$\d+/)
  .map((p,i)=>`${p}${matches[i]??''}`).join(''))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I rather do the URL approach.